# Why is a rational number whose $p$-adic valuation less than $1$ not a $p$-adic integer?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field with ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Consider a polynomial $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}(13x^5+121x^4+55x^2)$.

Each coefficient has $3$-adic absolute value $0$.

So it seems $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the set of $p$-adic numbers with additive valuation $\geq 0$ (i.e. multiplicative absolute value $\leq 1$). Note that $1/4 = 1/(1+3) = 1-3+3^2+\dots \in \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Totally agree with what @DouglasMolin writes, although to be honest I do not see a connection between question body and question title, *and* think that the question in the title is making a false statement: If it's the additive valuation, then rational numbers with $p$-adic valuation $0$ are still $p$-adic integers; if it's the multiplicative value, then indeed all rational numbers with $p$-adic value less than $1$ are $p$-adic integers.